# Is there a way to pass output from one step of AWS ssm document to another?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

I have an SSM document that I am using to run a PowerShell script and then invoke another SSM document. I want to pass output from the first SSM document to the second document.

```
{
  "schemaVersion": "2.2",
  "description": "This is to test copying a file from place a to b",
  "parameters": {
    "InputDir": {
      "type": "String",
      "description": "This is the input directory from where we are copying",
      "default": "C:\\himanshu\\AWS_SSM_WORK"
    },
    "OutputDir": {
      "type": "String",
      "description": "This is the output directory  where to we are copying",
      "default": ""
    }
  },
  "mainSteps": [
    {
      "action": "aws:runPowerShellScript",
      "name": "testCopyFunction",
      "inputs": {
        "timeoutSeconds": "60",
        "runCommand": [
          "write-Output {{InputDir }}",
          " $utility_path = '{{InputDir}}'",
          "$var = @{",
          " “name” = “himanshu” ",
          " “surname” = “rai” ",
          "}",
          " if (Test-Path $utility_path) ",
          "   { Set-Location $utility_path ",
          " Start-Process \"cmd.exe\" \" /k C:\\himanshu\\AWS_SSM_WORK\\start.bat \" ",
          " $var.Add(\"state\",\"up\") ",
          "}",
          " else ",
          "   { Write-Error \"Base location of build is incorrectly set.\" ",
          "     exit 1",
          "   }",
          "$var | ConvertTo-Json  | Out-File \".\\name.json\" "
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "action": "aws:runDocument",
      "name": "egsl_him_second",
      "inputs": {
        "documentType": "SSMDocument",
        "documentPath": "egsl_him_second",
        "documentParameters": {
          "InputDir": "C:\\himanshu\\AWS_SSM_WORK"
        },
        "finallyStep": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In the second step, I am calling another SSM document using aws:runDocument. Is there any way, I can use the $var in the second step that I have created in step1

Answer (score 1):

Upping my comment to a full answer. Assuming OP is using *Command* documents (which I presume from the fact that they are using `aws:runPowerShellScript`, which is a *Command* document plugin), the answer is that as of this writing (more than two years later) you cannot do this *with Command documents*. The documentation that the downvoted answer referred to applies to *Automation* documents, which are much more powerful.

I asked this question directly to AWS Support and was linked to this very page before they realized the distinction between Command and Automation documents, and after testing on their side they explicitly confirmed that this cannot be done with Command documents.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, since we weren't able to achieve this directly, if I recall correctly, we wrote the output from the first SSM doc to a JSON file, and then in the second SSM doc we parsed that JSON file to get the results from the first SSM doc.

Comment: Yeah, that's something that occurred to me as well.

Answer (score -1):

You can add **outputs** to your first step

```
    {
      "action": "aws:runPowerShellScript",
      "name": "testCopyFunction",
      "inputs": {
        "timeoutSeconds": "60",
        "runCommand": [
           ...
        ],
      },
      "outputs": [
          {
            "Name": "var",
            "Selector": "PATH_TO_JSON_ATTRIBUTE",
            "Type": "String"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

assuming you are getting a json output from your first step, you can replace **PATH_TO_JSON_ATTRIBUTE** with selector to assign json attribute value to **var** and use the same as input in your second step

```
      {
      "action": "aws:runDocument",
      "name": "egsl_him_second",
      "inputs": {
        "documentType": "SSMDocument",
        "documentPath": "egsl_him_second",
        "documentParameters": {
          "InputDir": "C:\\himanshu\\AWS_SSM_WORK",
          "var": "{{testCopyFunction.var}}"
        },
        "finallyStep": true
      }
    }
```

Comment: Doesnt work. It just passes the string "{{testCopyFunction.var}}".

Comment: For a better understanding of PropertySelector, inputs and outputs, please refer to the example provided in this documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/automation-actions.html

Comment: I know this is two years later, but after trying to understand exactly this behavior for hours, I *think* the answer is that OP, like me, is using a *Command* document, not an *Automation* document. And AFAICT the ability to capture the output of steps to pass to subsequent steps is restricted to Automation documents.